# Break even after 50 points

Tags: mql5

if
int InpUpperLevel=80;

Buy: if(cntBuy==0 && bufferMain[0]>(100-InpUpperLevel) && bufferMain[1]<=(100-InpUpperLevel))

Sell: if(cntSell==0 && bufferMain[0]<InpUpperLevel && bufferMain[1]>=InpUpperLevel)

= Opening a buy and sell position, what i seek is the code for block trailing after trade moves 50pips for MQL5

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.